# Dynatree image inside tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, dynatree

im using the jQuery Dynatree plug in a new site that im developing. 
Here is an example of how i wrote it

```
  var treevluData = [
{title: "Team 1", isFolder: true, tooltip: "Tooltip test", expand: true, children: [ {title: "Honda CBR",tooltip: "Tooltip test Honda CBR"} ] },
{title: "Team 2", isFolder: true, expand: true, key: "id3", children: [ {title: "BMW X3"},
                                                                           {title: "Honda CRX"},
                                                                           {title: "VW Golf"},
                                                                           {title: "Smart ForTwo"}
                                                                         ]},
{title: "Team 3", isFolder: true, key: "id4", expand: true, children: [ {title: "Fiat Doblo"} ]} ];
```

The tree is working fine and everything's ok with this. As you can see in the first child of team 1 i have set a tooltip. My question is if it possible and how could i put an image inside  the tooltip so everytime you mouseover a child it will show an image as tooltip instead of plain text. I know that you can do this with some CSS in html but i cant find how do to this in this plug in.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `tooltip` option is converted into a simple `<a titlie='...'>` attribute, that most browsers display as simple popoup.
As far as I  know, these tooltips cannot contain HTML markup.
I'd suggest to use one of the existing jQuery tootltip plugins instead and bind it to the Dynatree nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mar10. I found the easyTooltip plugin that i think suits to my needs. 
With this code

```
$("#vlutree a").easyTooltip({
useElement: "item"          
});
```

pointing to this div

```
<div id="item">
    <img src="icons/Icon.png" />
</div>
```

im able to put an img to the tooltip, my problem is how can i find in which node im pointing in order to show different images for each node..